# Itens da API não aparecem na tela, apenas no console

Tags: react

Preciso preencher uma tabela com os dados da minha API. Fiz um get para acessar a API e tentei colocar todos os itens dentro de um array dentro do meu state chamado "afps" e dei um setState para preencher esse array com os valores da API. De alguma forma no console ele me traz a requisição da api, porém quando eu faço um console log com o resultado da state não me traz nada.
[image: Imagem da requisição da api]
[image: imagem do console log do resultado da state]

```
class ListaAfps extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      afps: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try{

    const response = await listaAfps.get('');

    this.setState({ afps: response.data });

    }catch(e){

    }
  }
  render() {

    const { afps } = this.state;
    console.log({afps});
```

Comment: Você viu se ele está caindo no catch?

Comment: Sim, esta caindo no catch e retornando "Error: Network Error", porém como da pra ver na img a requisição do endpoint retorna normalmente.

Comment: já tentou isso?:
  async componentDidMount() {
    try{

    const response = await listaAfps.get('').then( v => {
           this.setState({ afps: v.data });
        }
    )

    }catch(e){

    }
  }

Comment: Fiz essa alteração, continua o mesmo problema.